# Unable to get All child data in Firebase Database using a Map?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display all child "name" located in my database tree. [My Database tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWMzs.png)  I used the Map to do so:

```
GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>> m = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>>() {};
Map<String, Object> map = snapshot.getValue(m);
String username = (String) map.get("name");
displayName.setText(username);// Display the name
```

I am displaying all the data into a recyclerView. But for some reasons instead of getting all names(Eva, smith, princess), I am only one which is the lastest one created "princess"  being displayed 3 times in my recyclerView layout(princess, princess, princess). Anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a node named `users` in which you have all those `uid's`, to get all those name, please use the code below. Is the easiest way to achieve this.

```
DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String userId = (String) dataSnapshot.getKey();

        DatabaseReference userIdRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
                 Log.d("TAG", name);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        userIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying but what do you mean by uid inside .child(uid)?

Comment: `uid` is a variable that takes place for your `uid1`, `uid2` and so on. You need to have that `uid` in order to use it in your `DatabaseReference`.

Comment: but if I do not have one. What I am trying to do is to get all children named "name" inside my node "users". Since the uid of each user is always different reason why I use a Map to skip the user's uid in order to take only the child "name" inside each user's uid.

Comment: DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid); I think using this one will only get me the value name of a specific user due to the uid

Comment: In this case, i think the `DatabaseReference` is wrong becase the code works fine. Can you please add a more detailed picture of your database, including the root?

Comment: This Method seems working too because when I Toast it or use Log.d("TAG", name) it is displaying correctly on LogCat. But it is not the case on the screen(phone) since is only displaying one name 3 times(princess, princess, princess). I want to get (Eva, smith, princess) on my recyclerView. Since the Toast is getting all data but not the RecyclerView, do you thing something is wrong with the RecyclerView. Thanks again for trying to help me

Comment: If you say that `Log.d("TAG", name)` is displaying the data correctly in LogCat, it means that the code works fine and you can get the data out from the Firebase database as you wanted. My concern is, that something is wrong with your RecyclerView. Because the problem regarding the `RecyclerView` is not related with the initial question, i suggest you add a new one, so me or other users can answer it.

Comment: If you still think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Sure... By the way I asked another about that and I provide my FirebaseRecyclerAdapter Code which I think is where the problem is. Link for the question [Here]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190205/firebaserecyleradapter-only-returning-one-value-on-my-screen