# Why My FirebaseRecylerAdapter Not Working Properly?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to display all child "name" located in [My Database tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueA5T.png). I used this answer given by @Alex Mamo [Unable to get All child data in Firebase Database using a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169044/unable-to-get-all-child-data-in-firebase-database-using-a-map) 
I want to display all the data into a recyclerView. But for some reasons instead of getting all names(Eva, smith, princess) on my Screen Phone, I am only able to see one "princess" which is being displayed 3 times in my recyclerView layout(princess, princess, princess). After playing around with Alex's answer, I found this worked perfectly in my case,

```
 DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String name = dataSnapshot1.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    displayName.setText(name);// display on the screen

                    Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }
```

So since this answer give me all names correctly in a Toast but not on my screen, so I assume that something is wrong with my FirebaseRecyclerAdpater. Here my code so far,

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UsersPostClass,  UsersViewHolder> userList = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UsersPostClass,  UsersViewHolder>(
            UsersPostClass.class,
            R.layout.custom,
             UsersViewHolder.class,
            mDatabaseRef
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder( UsersViewHolder viewHolder, UsersPostClass model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setUsernameList(getApplicationContext());


        }
    };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(userList);
}

private static class  UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public  UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setUsernameList(final Context context) {
        final TextView displayName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.listViewUsername);
        DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String name = dataSnapshot1.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    displayName.setText(name);

                    Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };
        yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }
}
```

Any Help or tip is welcome.
EDIT: Adding my Layout
This is my RecyclerView Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="My Players List"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Lastly my Custom Layout where I want to display all Names

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listViewUsername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Username"
            android:textColor="#aaa"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Just to have a Visual of what I am talking this a Screenshot of what I am getting(princess, princess, princess) when I should get (Eva,smith, princess). [My ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCt86.png) If you look closer down you can see the Toast is returning "Eva" and 2 other names properly but not on Screen.

Comment: Can you provide us you .XML file?

Comment: @AlexMamo Added Pls take a look again

Comment: Try to change in your `Custom Layout` the `RelativeLayout` with a `LinearLayout` and make both `layout_width` and `layout_height` as `wrap_content` like this: `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and  `android:layout_height="wrap_content" `. Does it work?

Comment: Nope. By the way I added a picture just to give you a visual of what I am talking about. Thanks for trying to help tho

Comment: Try to change `UsersPostClass` with `String` class in your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: What do you mean? Replace everywhere `UsersPostClass` with `String`. If that was the case it did not work at all. Just getting the same name three times. Pls could you try it in a new project and let me know if you are getting the same result than me too?

Comment: I think it's a matter of displaying the items, not a database query. You want 
 to query, everything it's ok, you want to display, you have duplicates. Try to use a `FirebaseListAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still getting the same thing even with `FirebaseListAdapter`. I am just going to move on by using a constructor and call it via model. I think that's the last option left to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> displayName.setText(name);// display on the screen
> ```

You put this in a loop, where `displayName` is only a **singluar** UI element. In other words, you'll always only see the very last name from the loop.

If you notice, your linked post there doesn't have any loop

You need to populate some ArrayList

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String name = dataSnapshot1.child("name").getValue().toString();
    names.add(name);
}

displayName.setText(names.toString());
Toast.makeText(context, names.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You can use that list in your RecyclerView, instead

Comment: Now I am getting [Eva, smith, princess] being displayed 3 times like that. Clearly the answer is so close..

Comment: Same with Toast too

Comment: Like I said, you need to 1) Create a new adapter 2) See it to your RecyclerView... You can't use FirebaseRecyclerView library here

Comment: Thanks now it is working fine now I forgot to create a new Adapter with your method